# Clonezilla back up mapped partition in /dev/mapper/

Tags: backup, luks, clonezilla

Every time I do a full system image backup, Clonezilla copies the ~200GiB of free space of my LUKS encrypted home partition too.

Now, I have unencryped it as `/dev/mapper/luks-some-numbers` and want to back up that one instead. But Clonezilla doesn't seem to find it. It only shows the "normal" partition in its selection list.

Comment: Try this: https://www.errietta.me/blog/luks-clonezilla/